# Fetch requirejs.config from Gruntfile

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, requirejs

Is there any way to import a requirejs config in to my grunt config file? Right now I have to keep two identical versions, one in `app/main.js` and one in my `Gruntfile.js`:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) { 

    // can I import app/main.js requireConfig here?

    var requireConfig = { 
         paths: {
             jquery: 'lib/jquery'
             // etc...
         } 
    };
});
```

My main.js looks something like this:

```
requirejs.config({ 
     paths: {
         jquery: 'lib/jquery'
         // etc...
     } 
});

define(['app'], function(app){
    app.start();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard module pattern which supports different type of module system like following.

Your requirejs config file like this

amd-config.js

```
(function(factory) {
    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
      // Register as an AMD module if available...
      define('amd-config', [], factory());
    } else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
      // Next for Node.js, CommonJS, browserify...
      module.exports = factory();
    } else {
      // setting browser global when none of the above are available
      window.amdConfig = factory();
    }
  }

  (function() {
    var amdConfig = {
        baseUrl: 'scripts',
        paths: {
           //Paths here
        }
    };
    return amdConfig;
  }));
```

In gruntfile you can just require like any other module.

```
var requireConfig = require('amd-config');
```

Include it normally like you do in index.html with script tag before app.js
and then in app.js use it like following.

```
requirejs.config(window.amdConfig);

define(['app'], function(app){
    app.start();
});
```

PS: There are cleaner way of including it in app.js.

1. More cleaner than second, create global variable require and include the script before requirejs script. requirejs checks if there is global variable with name require containing object. If its there, it is used as a config object. So you dont have to call requirejs.config  yourself.
2. You can require the file like you require other files. In that case it will be treated as a require module and you will receive the object in require callback. call your requirejs.config like following.

```

```
require(['amd-config'], function(amdConfig){
   requirejs.config(amdConfig);

   require(['app'], function(app){
      app.start();
   });
});
```

```

Answer (score 1):

A simpler approach you could use, if you are using grunt to build the project. You can simply use:

```
options:{
   mainConfigFile: "path/to/Config.js"
}
```

granted you need to use:
https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-requirejs

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Is it possible to add more properties to it? I.e. extend/merge it

Comment: Technically yes, if you do it in another build step  before you use the config file in require, but that might not be a very good solution. Alternatively [bundlesConfigOutFile](HTTPS://github.com/requirejs/r.js/blob/98a9949480d68a781c8d6fc4ce0a07c16a2c8a2a/build/example.build.js#L641) might help you, but I've never used it myself.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```js
function getRequireConfig(requireFilePath) {

  var config;
  var configFileContent,
   _require;

  _require = require; 
  require = { 
   data: {},
   config : function (configParam) {
    this.data = configParam;
   },
   get : function () {
    return this.data;
   }
  };
 
  configFileContent = readFileSync(requireFilePath);
  eval(configFileContent); 

  config = require.get();

  require = _require; 

  return config;
 }
```

What it is doing is:

1. Override require definition to a custom implementation
2. Load require config file
3. Eval it so that the config function of custom implementation will be
4. called  Get the config object from data

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was hoping for something a little less... hacky :)